# Get Azure diagnostic settings information associated to a resources

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

Is there any way in azure to gather the information about which resources have associated the diagnostic logs settings?

I was exploring graph but is not possible yet, I was maybe exploring azure data explorer but with no success. I know that using PowerShell and az cli I can retrieve diagnostic information, but I as looking for something more straight forward to do so.

the idea is check which resources have associated certain options in the azure diagnostic logs settings and which ones don't

Comment: Why don’t you use Azure Policy for this?

Comment: Have you tried any approach so far? If yes, Could you share it here? @John Wilmar Herrera Gil

Comment: The idea is to create a query with the information about what specific settings have each resource, cause they are different depending on the kind of resource. for example, an app service only should have enabled metrics, and the storage accounts logs @Niclas

Answer (score 1):

> Get Azure diagnostic settings information associated to a resources:

When it comes to Azure CLI to retrieve the diagnostic settings linked to an Azure resource, you can below command as shown below.

```bash
az monitor diagnostic-settings list --resource staging-testwebsite-app --resource-group xxxx --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites
```

[image]

But as you mentioned, you need a different approach to achieve the same requirement. For that, use below KQL query `AzureDiagnostics` table which gives your required outcome. Change the type of the resource provider accordingly.

```bash
AzureDiagnostics
| where Type == "Microsoft.Web/sites"
| project ResourceId, Resource
```

[image]

*Note:* I would suggest you using CLI or REST API the better options to achieve your requirement without any conflicts in case of large amount of data.